# Why does the method .is_a? returning other values other than true or false?

Tags: arrays, ruby, symbols

I was expecting symbols to return true or false in the array,but why does it return the values of of the elements that are true. More specifically, how does .is_a? work, I thought it returns true or false.

```
my_array = ["raindrops", :kettles, "whiskers", :mittens, :packages]

symbol_filter = lambda {|x| x.is_a? Symbol}
symbols = my_array.select(&symbol_filter)
puts symbols
```

I expected the output of true or false, but the output was

```
[:kettles, :mittens, :packages].
```

Comment: `is_a?` returns true or false, but `select` returns the items in your sequence that matched the given predicate. You're printing the output of `select`, not the output of `is_a?`

Comment: Try `map` rather than `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Use collect to get your desired output

```
my_array = ["raindrops", :kettles, "whiskers", :mittens, :packages]

symbol_filter = lambda {|x| x.is_a? Symbol}
symbols = my_array.collect(&symbol_filter)
puts symbols
```

O/p

```
2.4.0 :066 >     symbols = my_array.collect(&symbol_filter)
=> [false, true, false, true, true]
```

Comment: `collect` is an alias of `map`. Some people (and robots) prefer `map`.